# How can I use advanced/nested type variables with arrow functions?

Tags: typescript

How can I write "advanced/nested" type variables, like `T` is being used in this function declaration, with arrow functions?

```
function wrapInObject<T>(key: string) {
  return (x: T) => ({ [key]: x });
}
```

I've tried/want to do something like this, but it does not work.

```
const wrapInObject = <T>(key: string) => (x: T) => ({ [key]: x });
```

Comment: What specific error are you getting, I copy pasted your code and it compiles

Comment: Oh, should've probably included, or even looked at, that. Seems like tsc thinkt I'm trying to write JSX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the comments the error occurs when the generic arrow function is written in a `tsx` file. In `ts` the syntax in the question works fine.

This is a known limitation of generics in `tsx` files due to the ambiguities in the syntax, which is documented [here](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/generics.html). As suggested in the link, you can get around it by adding a type constraint to `T`

```
const wrapInObject = <T extends {}>(key: string) => (x: T) => ({ [key]: x });
```